# Yourkit profile save snapshot file before shutdown

Tags: profiler, yourkit

I use YourKit profiler on linux on a UAT server as an agent.
The configs are:

```
agentpath:/home/build/libyjpagent.so=sampling,monitors,delay=25200000
```

The .snapshot file is save only when I shutdown the application. How can I get the snapshot without stopping the application? 
telemetrylimit is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only capture snapshots periodically
https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/periodic.jsp

or connect to a profiled application via YourKit client tool and click button "Capture snapshot"
https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/connect.jsp

Comment: Including an overview of the process is more helpful than just links to external resources.